# Should or should not declare exceptions during interface definition?

Tags: c#, interface, exception

This question confuses me lots, and for a long time. I noticed there are similar questions had been asked, but there is not a perfect answer for me.
What confuses me are:

1. if I declare exceptions during interface definition, actually, there probably are multiple implementations for a same interface, and different people probably throws different exceptions. I think we should not restrict so tight of interface.
2. On another hand, if we don't declare exceptions, it's not easy for us to know what exceptions a method probably throw during interface programming. In this way, the interface user had to know details of the interface implementation.

So, what's the balance point? which way should I follow? Or maybe my understanding about interface programming is wrong.

Thanks so much.

Comment: @Steve, Yes, I ever read that page, I don't get a clear yes or no.

Comment: @feng The thing is, this kind of thing has no definite answers. There is no clear yes no answer.

Comment: @Sweeper, oh, just based on favor? What's your habit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not bind the user which implements the interface to strict exceptions. He/She maybe need to implement own exception types or throwing other exceptions then you normaly think of. This is based on how abstract your interface is. If you think on `IList` which exceptions can be thrown on `Add(object item);`? You can't know this, if you create the interface, because let's say I want to make new class as following:

```
public class FileList : IList
{
   public void Add(object item)
   {
      try
      {
      }
      //Here I could need this Exception which you can't know on interface-Level
      catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

This is just my opinion and you won't ever get a clear answer how to use this. If you really need or want to mark the exceptions on interface level I would recommend you the XML-Comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds an object to your List
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">The Item to Add</param>
/// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException"></exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. What is your code habit? Not restrict?

Comment: My habit is to not restrict this :)